# How to solve overheating problem?

Tags: nvidia, dell, overheating, temperature

I have windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10 installed.
My laptop specs are
Dell XPS 15
4gb RAM
Nvidia gt540m

I've been searching for hours but can't figure out a solution. I am a complete newbie to ubuntu. I've installed tlp but the only thing I was able to do with it was to know my cpu temperature is 75C. I executed sudo tlp start but there hasn't been any change in temperature.

Comment: Try PerfectDisk. It might be issues with your hard drive.

Comment: Those Dell laptops have turbo instructions for the CPU that sometimes cause overheating with sustained use. Even on Windows I sometimes had to use an app called ThrottleStop to prevent it from being used. Perhaps you can check how the CPU is being used somehow?

Comment: How do i check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too use Dell XPS 15 and have suffered from over-heating in past when I used open source `nvidia-nouveau` (installed from additional drivers).

Problem got solved when I started using `bumblebee` where you can manually switch between intel graphics and nvidia graphics. Nvidia graphics gives much better performance but is also power expensive which results into overheating. Bumblebee gives you option to use only graphic heavy applications with nvidia graphics thus reducing overheating.

Guide to [Install Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)

After installation you can run any application with nvidia graphics by using `optirun <application-name>` from terminal.

Also you can try `indicator-cpufreq` which lets you put your profile to conservative, also reduce CPU frequency from applet-icon to prevent overheating when computational load is low.

Comment: I followed it but I get this :  
abhyudaya@abhyudaya-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~/Django/mysite/mysite$ sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee-nvidia
E: Unable to locate package virtualgl

Comment: did you add bumblebee repository using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable` and 'sudo apt-get update` before installation?

Comment: yes I did all the steps

Comment: Oops! Sorry buddy looks like 12.10 is not supported from ppa:bumblebee/stable.

Comment: However you can install using source http://bumblebee-project.org/bumblebee-3.2.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have Nvidia's own binary driver installed and not the open-source version that comes with Ubuntu (run Additional Drivers)...

Then install Bumblebee in the software centre so you can switch between your build in Intel graphics and Nvidia graphics, otherwise both will be running at the same time and your laptop will overheat and run out of battery quickly...

Comment: how do i make sure i have the binary driver installed?

Comment: I followed the instructions here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee  but i get this error   
abhyudaya@abhyudaya-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~/Django/mysite/mysite$ sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee-nvidia
E: Unable to locate package virtualgl

Answer (score 0):

Also happens to some HP laptops, such as my Probook 4530s. The solution is to check for a BIOS update from Dell.

Go http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/ProductSelector/Select/FamilySelection?CategoryPath=all-products%2Fesuprt_laptop%2Fesuprt_xps_laptop&Family=XPS&DisplayCrumbs=Product%2520Type%40%2CLaptops%40%2CXPS&rquery=na

Select your laptop, then under BIOS, get the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same laptop, but I was on Windows and used ThrottleStop to prevent turbo mode from being activated. This stopped overheating during games and other CPU intensive operations.

Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/259535/29877) question as well as the tag [turbo-boost]